# How can I insert data from two tables into one?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three tables , both with the same fields as in the example below:

Table:

```
dog
-------------
name, date
```

Table :

```
cat
-------------
name, date
```

Table:

```
animal
-------------
name, date
```

as I transfer the dog and cat data for animal table ? I tried the select into but could not do it with two tables.

```
Table value:

CAT
name      date
Garfield  2015-08-03

DOG
name      date
Spike     2015-08-03
```

Source:

```
insert into animal values ((select * from cat,dog))
```

Expected result

```
ANIMAL
name     date
Garfield 2015-08-03
Spike    2015-08-03
```

Comment: Could you post what you tried?  What is the source data and what are you expecting to see as the final results?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server: Select from two tables and insert into one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21957698/sql-server-select-from-two-tables-and-insert-into-one)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
insert into animal 
select name, date from dog
union all
select name, date from cat
```

Comment: thank you with this script I arrived at my expected result , this and the appropriate response , thank you all

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with the execution of a query ie:Join operation.Table 1, Table 2,table 3. We have the same attribute in all these three tables.Just join the attributes with table1.fieldname JOIN table2.fieldname JOIN table3.fieldname

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to do a JOIN as there is no relationship between them.

```
Insert Into animal (name, [date])
Select name, [date]
from dog, cat
```